# When planning for inheritance, are constructers allowed to call overridable method?

Tags: java, effective-java

From Effective Java 2nd edition, item 17:

> For each public or protected method or constructor, the documentation
>   must indicate which overridable methods the method or constructor
>   invokes

Later in the same item it says:

> Constructors must not invoke overridable methods, directly or indirectly.

Aren't these two statements contradictory, or am I missing something?

Comment: You can read it in a sense which is non-contradictory: it can be vacuuosly true a constructor's documentation indicates all overridable methods invoked, if there are zero overridable methods invoked. But I suspect that's not the spirit in which it was written, nor the one that you are meaning :)

Comment: Not really, you should document which overridable members you invoke, just so somebody can override them, and afterwards can 't say 

> "hey, but you never informed me overriding this or that wouldn't have
> any side effects"

That aside, there always will be people changing methods in their (overriden) classes, which might break your code, so it is best never to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking overridable methods during construction is **Allowed** - there is nothing illegal about this.

Invoking overridable methods during construction is **NOT Advisable** - It is generally ill-advised to invoke overridable methods during construction because this can cause incomplete objects to be exposed and restricts the predictability of the system.

```
public class A {

    final int a;

    public A() {
        a = method();
    }

    protected int method() {
        return 42;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{" + "a=" + a + '}';
    }

}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected int method() {
        System.out.println("this=" + this);
        return 96;
    }

}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("B = " + new B());
}
```

Note that your first quote only refers to the documentation, not the code. I would suggest the only issue is the use of **must** when **should** would probably be more appropriate.